# Unclear Sqlite exception after updating my UWP app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite, uwp

After updating the UWP  app, I get many crash from the different sections of the app

> STOWED_EXCEPTION_Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException_80131500***APP-NAME***.dll!Microsoft::Data::Sqlite::SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader

Which did not happend in previous version, I also did not change the database access code section nor updated/reinstalled the EF Sqlite nugget package.
Here are Stacktrace i have received from users:

Thanks

> ```
> Frame   Image   Function    Offset
> ```
>
> 0   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll   Microsoft::Data::Sqlite::Interop::MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC 0x0000000000000067
>   1   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll   Microsoft::Data::Sqlite::SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader    0x000000000000012F
>   2   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll   Microsoft::Data::Sqlite::SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader  0x000000000000000B
>   3   EntityFramework.Relational.dll  Microsoft::Data::Entity::Storage::Internal::RelationalCommand::__c__DisplayClass17_0._ExecuteReader_b__0$catch$0    0x0000000000000013
>   4   SharedLibrary.dll   System::Func$1_System::__Canon_.Invoke  0x0000000000000013
>   5   EntityFramework.Relational.dll  Microsoft::Data::Entity::Storage::Internal::RelationalCommand.Execute_System.__Canon_$catch$0   0x00000000000000C1
>   6   EntityFramework.Relational.dll  Microsoft::Data::Entity::Storage::Internal::RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader 0x0000000000000057
>   7   EntityFramework.Relational.dll  Microsoft::Data::Entity::Query::Internal::QueryingEnumerable::Enumerator.MoveNext   0x000000000000008B
>   8   EntityFramework.Relational.dll  Microsoft::Data::Entity::Query::QueryMethodProvider.GetResult_System.Int32_ 0x000000000000003D
>   9   ***APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll    _$ILCT$::$ILT$ReflectionDynamicInvoke$.InvokeRetOI_System.__Canon,*System.Int32*    0x0000000000000061
>   10  SharedLibrary.dll   System::InvokeUtils.CallIHelperStaticCallWithInstantiation  0x0000000000000023
>   11  SharedLibrary.dll   System::InvokeUtils.CallDynamicInvokeMethod 0x0000000000000119
>   12  System.Linq.Expressions System::Linq::Expressions::Interpreter::MethodInfoCallInstruction.InvokeWorker$catch$0  0x0000000000000017
>   13  System.Linq.Expressions System::Linq::Expressions::Interpreter::MethodInfoCallInstruction.Invoke    0x0000000000000009
>   14  System.Linq.Expressions System::Linq::Expressions::Interpreter::MethodInfoCallInstruction.Run   0x0000000000000065
>   15  System.Linq.Expressions System::Linq::Expressions::Interpreter::Interpreter.Run 0x0000000000000027
>   16  System.Linq.Expressions System::Linq::Expressions::Interpreter::LightLambda.Run 0x000000000000009B
>   17  SharedLibrary.dll   System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ConditionalWeakTable$2_System::__Canon,System::__Canon_::CreateValueCallback.InvokeObjectArrayThunk  0x0000000000000037
>   18  EntityFramework.Core.dll    Microsoft::Data::Entity::Query::Internal::QueryCompiler::__c__DisplayClass18_1$1_System::Int32_._CompileQuery_b__1$catch$0  0x0000000000000059
>   19  SharedLibrary.dll   System::Comparison$1_System::__Canon_.Invoke    0x0000000000000013
>   20  EntityFramework.Core.dll    Microsoft::Data::Entity::Query::Internal::QueryCompiler.Execute_System.Int32_   0x000000000000003D
>   21  EntityFramework.Core.dll    Microsoft::Data::Entity::Query::Internal::EntityQueryProvider.Execute_System.Int32_ 0x0000000000000033
>   22  System.Linq.Queryable.dll   System::Linq::Queryable.Count_System.Int32_ 0x0000000000000121
>   23  **APPNAME***.exe    InstagramDownloader::pgHome._imgDownloader_b__15_4  0x0000000000000167
>   24  **APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll Windows::System::Threading::TimerElapsedHandler.Invoke  0x000000000000000F
>   25  **APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll McgInterop::ReverseComSharedStubs.Proc_ 0x0000000000000015
>   26  SharedLibrary.dll   System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw 0x0000000000000019
>   27  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess   0x0000000000000053
>   28  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification  0x000000000000002D
>   29  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd  0x000000000000001D
>   30  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.GetResult    0x000000000000000B
>   31  **APPNAME***.exe    InstagramDownloader::pgHome::_imgDownloader_d__15.MoveNext  0x00000000000015AF
>   32  SharedLibrary.dll   System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw 0x0000000000000019
>   33  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess   0x0000000000000053
>   34  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification  0x000000000000002D
>   35  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd  0x000000000000001D
>   36  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter.GetResult    0x000000000000000B
>   37  **APPNAME***.exe    InstagramDownloader::pgHome::_btnDownload_Click_d__17.MoveNext  0x000000000000025D
>   38  **APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll McgInterop::McgHelpers.ThrowFailed  0x0000000000000033
>   39  **APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll McgInterop::ComCallHelpers.ComCall__HRESULT 0x00000000000000A9
>   40  **APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll McgInterop::ForwardComSharedStubs.Func_TResult___System.__Canon,_System.__Canon_    0x000000000000002B
>   41  **APPNAME***.McgInterop.dll Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog.ShowAsync    0x0000000000000011
>   42  **APPNAME***.exe    InstagramDownloader::pgHome::_btnDownload_Click_d__17.MoveNext$catch$0  0x000000000000002F
>   43  SharedLibrary.dll   System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw 0x0000000000000019
>   44  System.Private.Threading    System::Runtime::CompilerServices::AsyncMethodBuilderCore::__c._ThrowAsync_b__9_0   0x0000000000000013
>   45  System.Private.Threading    System::Threading::WinRTSynchronizationContext::Invoker.InvokeCore  0x0000000000000033

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating all SQLite-related packages on NuGet as well as the SQLite extension for Visual Studio (via Tools -> Extensions and Updates...)

### Update

As I have learned, you use `EntityFrameworkCore`, which works only with Windows 10 Fall Creators Update and newer and will not work on older versions of UWP. To get rid of the issues, you will have to set your app to have minimum SDK version 16299 (FCU). If you need to support older versions, you will have to work without Entity Framework for now...

Comment: no updates. I'm using "EntityFramework.Sqlite" [link](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8313926284/efsqlite.PNG) nugget pkg to access Sqlite database by EF , but I can't find new version for this pre-release package now, also i cant find suitable package that work on my uwp app with minimum version target (10.0.10586) build, 
Unfortunately This article just work on Fall creators update [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started)

Comment: Is problem fixed by installing and using the lower versions of this package (EntityFrameworkCore)? Instead of the new version, I have installed version 1.4.1 (current build 10.0.15063) everything seems works but I'm not sure for older Windows builds like 10.0.1586.

Comment: I am afraid not. The older versions still need Fall Creators Update to work properly as far as I know.